# What level of detail is required in gherkin formatted test scenarios to support automated testing?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, gherkin

I manage a testing team and the developers want our documented test scenarios to create automated regression testing (of a web-based tool). Our scenarios are written in gherkin format (Given/When/Then) but I'm wondering how much detail is needed to support automated testing? For example, our 'Then's are pretty general like

'then the user should be asked to select their country'

but do not include the specifics like where the drop down box should be, what values should be in it, what font size it should be, what order the options should be in, etc.

How much detail will they need?

I don't know what tool they are using for automation yet, they are still evaluating the options. Possibly Selenium.

Comment: Depending on the context, it is possible that the maintainability of the test can go down if you add more details. Based on your question I would first perform a proof of concept...

Answer (score 1):

Make it short, simple, reusable and powerful gherkin commands. It should help QA, business/product and DEV teams to understand the use cases clearly, most importantly the automation qa team should be able to understand each step and automate it independently, irrespective of flows (for re-usability). The standard way i would recommend to frame all of your gherkin commands (test steps) in this format:

```
When <action by user> in <unique page identifier>
Then <expectation> in <unique page identifier>
```

The second part 'unique page identifier' is not always needed if your AUT is small or having lesser pages.

Example (without page identifiers)

```
When login to gmail using myuser001 user
Then mailbox should be displayed
When switching to inbox
Then number of unread messages should be 10
```

Another example (with page identifiers)

```
When login to order booking website using myuser001 user
Then home page should be displayed with welcome message 'myuser001 user'

When searching for product 'onions' in products page
Then expecting the search results should be at least 1

When adding the product onion and quantity 2 from search results page
Then cart should have count 1
And confirm checkout from cart

When the payment and shipping details are entered
Then placing the order should display confirmation message
```